# how big of a base do you need to support a 6' post

Tags: mechanical-engineering

With a floating base what is the size and weight that you would need to support a 6 foot post that needs to handle hanging 300 pounds on it.

Comment: how is the weight attached?

Comment: Is this a load perpendicular through the centre line of the post or offset?

Comment: Don't forget that there are multiple ways to solve this. You can avoid capsizing by placing something heavier below to keep it naturally upright, or you can make a base so wide that it is unlikely to tip.

Comment: You need to address the issues in the comments.  As written, your question can not be answered.